# How to configure RabbitVCS?

Tags: ubuntu, svn, rabbitvcs

I have installed rabbitvcs-core and rabbitvcs-nautilus on Ubuntu 11.10. I have the IP address of our SVN server and have no trouble using TortiseSVN from a Windows 7 PC. How do I configure RabbitVCS to make a working directory and work with our SVN server? I can't find anything in the RabbitVCS FAQ or docs.

Comment: Should this be asked instead at superuser.com or serverfault.com?

Comment: @jsalonen: if so, how can it be moved?

Comment: I'll send this question on to rabbitvcs@googlegroups.com and post the response (if any) here. Based on what I see in http://groups.google.com/group/rabbitvcs it may be that rabbitvcs is not yet supported in Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: Never mind. Let's keep it here.

Comment: I flagged it, but I guess it does match the scope detailed in http://stackoverflow.com/faq ("software tools commonly used by programmers")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RabbitVCS is suppose to be like TortoiseSVN on Windows. That is, when you right-click on a directory, you should see a context menu and in that context menu should be Subversion commands that allow you to do checkouts, etc.

I don't have a Linux system with Nautilus installed on it, so I can't give you the details. However, you might have to restart Nautilus (easiest way is to logout and login). Beyond that, I can't help you.

And, there's not much information on the project's website. The Wiki contains an FAQ that answers 9 questions (and none of the answers are that detailed), and a four line instructions on how to remove RabbitVCS.

Excuse me while I get on my soapbox here...

<soapbox>

To all of you people who run various open source projects: A Wiki is not *documentation*. You don't simply say *"Hey, let's install a Wiki"* and think that documentation will handle itself.

***YOU HAVE TO CREATE YOUR OWN DOCUMENTATION***

Yeah, I shouted it *and* put caplocks on, but I don't know how many open source projects I've seen without any documentation who think a Google group and Wiki suffice. If you create an open source project:

- Put in what your software does and a general overview of how it works.
- Let me know what's required. What operating systems? What other packages do I need. I want to know before I download and attempt to install it.
- Give me a complete installation documentation. Explain step by step and include command lines. Tell me what I should do or look for if some part of the install instruction doesn't work.
- Create a complete user's manual. Don't simply list the commands it can do. Let me know how to use it. Give me a basic workflow, so I understand how it works.
- If there is any sort of administration task, there should be some sort of administration manual with it. And, let me know about how I can diagnose the most common issues.
- And, most important of all: Keep the documentation up to date.
- Have a support mailing list and ***MONITOR*** it. I've seen a lot of active groups with threads like this:
- I had this particular problem...
- Me too.
- Yeah, I had it too.
- Does anyone know how to fix it?
- No, but if you find an answer, post it here...

That's better than some which are more like this:

- I had this particular problem...
- Hello?
- Anyone here?

A beautiful example on how to do things right in this regard is the Subversion project. They have a beautiful on line manual (which is available in book form) that goes through how to install Subversion, the basic workflows, how to use it, how to administer it, and some basic dos and don'ts. The manual is continuously updated.

If you have a question, someone on the mailing list can usually answer it. If not, a developer will pipe in and answer the question.

One of the reasons why Subversion became so popular so quickly was their support documentation and community. If you want your open source project to succeed, the documentation must be good.

Yeah, I know you don't like to write. You're a developer and not a tech writer. However, the documentation is just as important to your project as the actual code. In fact, good user documentation improves code because it gives developers a framework on how things work.

</soapbox>

Comment: That is why I installed it - it is supposed to be like TortoiseSVN on Windows which I am familiar with and there seems to be some community agreement that RabbitVCS is one of the better Ubuntu counterparts to TortoiseSVN. Logging out and in doesn't help. Thanks for your rant, though. Perhaps the authors will take this advise.

Comment: Hi, I used to be one of the main developers on the RabbitVCS project. As for your rant. What you don't seem to realize is that everything you mentioned requires effort on the part of somebody. 

I asked the last maintainer if it wasn't a good idea to simply close the project down because of all the high expectations from "users".  Replace the homepage with a single image, close down the mailing lists and be done with it.

Comment: Also your characterization that "we" threw up a wiki and thought documentation would just magically appear is totally incorrect. A wiki is just a tool to enable you to easily edit and publish documents (in the broadest sense of the word). When I was maintainer I put a lot of effort in writing documentation, assisting users and improving the code to make it easier to understand for people (and myself). Was the result anywhere close to good enough? No, far from it. But I rather quickly lost any motivation I had to work on the project.

Comment: @BrucevanderKooij I've worked on source projects. I understand the time & effort it takes. You may mock your "user's" high expectation. However, your users are developers. They aren't looking for someone to walk them to school. They're technical and know how to install and use software. They simply want something that works. Before answering this question, I went to the RabbitVCS webpage and mailing list: Found nada. I Googled: Found a lot of people having the same problems, but no answers. Look at TortoiseSVN. They have a 200 page manual and an active mailing list. That's why it's so popular.

Comment: @DavidW. Your points are quite valid.  I, unfortunately, do not agree with some of them.  We shall have to agree to disagree!

Comment: Rant aside -- The question isn't actually _solved_ that I can see.  Anyway this post: [nemo-RabbitVCS extension](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=180427), my help.  I had config files owned by `root` in my `.config/rabbitvcs/... ` directory.  I made things owned by me and restarted `nemo`.  That looks good, working so far.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that if the context menu doesn't come up I can go to another position on the window, like lower and to the left, click again and it comes up. It is not a real bug just a quirk in the interface.

There is always the svn commandline to fall back on, for example to clear up conflicts.

I recommend to people who have trouble with rabbitvcs that they try svn commands to see if the problems are deeper than rabbitvcs.